# Mongo query on dynamic fields in embedded document

Tags: mongodb

I have the following structure :

```
{
   "FiledA" : "FiledAValue",
   "FiledB" : "FiledBValue",
   "FiledC" : {
          "X" : "XValue",
          "Y" : "YValue",
          "Z" : "ZValue"
   },
}
```

- **FiledC** content may be dynamic (other fileds than x,y,z)
- The user will send a query like `{"FiledA" : "12" , "FiledC" : "333"}`
  The query should match 12 for FiledA and if there any FiledC which one of its filds contains 333

**How I can solve the FiledC issue in  a query** ?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: You don't want to have dynamic field's name in your documents. It's hard to work with. You should consider to change your documents structure and make `FieldC` an array of sub-documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use dynamic fields to query. It is not possible to query on these fields without individually inspecting all the fields. The similar approach has been exemplified at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802502/mongodb-query-help-query-on-values-of-any-key-in-a-sub-object/19802670#19802670)

If you are open to changing your schema, I would recommend changing it to :

```
{
   FieldC:[
      {name:"X", value:"value1"},
      {name:"Y", value:"value2"},
      {name:"Z", value:"value3"}
   ]
}
```

You can now query using :

```
db.collection.find({"FieldC.value":"testValue"});
```