# Mongoose: How can I query on a field with Array/Object type?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the data in MongoDB like following:

```
{

  _id: ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxx'), 
  data: {
   key1: value 1,
   key2: value 2,
   ...
   } 
 ...
}
```

I use **Mongoose** in Node.js app to connect to **MongoDB**.
I want to query all objects which the **data** field contains a certain string i.e: 'apple'

```
{
     data: {
        ...
        key3: 'I'd like to eat apple'
        ....
     }
}
```

How can I make this kind of query with **Mongoose**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Query Help - query on values of any key in a sub-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802502/mongodb-query-help-query-on-values-of-any-key-in-a-sub-object)

Comment: You could definitely consider restructuring your schema as mentioned in the  aforementioned link.  One thing that also may help you with your problem is that you can use find like this... db.collection.find({'data.key3': /apple/}) and it will match your document.