# Can I index a key in a multidimensional array?

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a collection with documents like this

```
{
    "top_key" : [
        [
            {
                "key" : "value1"
            },
            {
                "key" : "value2"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "key" : "value3"
            },
            {
                "key" : "value4"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Can I create an index for `key`?

Comment: No. [the doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#limitations) reads: "Multikey indexes can be constructed over arrays that hold both scalar values and nested documents". 

Nested arrays are neither documents nor scalars.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this SO answer: [MongoDB Query Help - query on values of any key in a sub-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802502/mongodb-query-help-query-on-values-of-any-key-in-a-sub-object#answer-19803016)

NOTE: This answer contains suggestion to update the schema in order to achieve desired result.
Change the schema from:

```
{
    "top_key" : [
        [
            {
                "key" : "value1"
            },
            {
                "key" : "value2"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "key" : "value3"
            },
            {
                "key" : "value4"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

to something like this:

```
{
    "top_key" : [
        {
            key_name: "key", key_value: "value1"
        },
        {
            key_name: "key", key_value: "value2"
        },
        {
            key_name: "key", key_value: "value3"
        },
        {
            key_name: "key", key_value: "value4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can index on `top_key.key_value` and query in a way:

```
db.settings.ensureIndex({ "top_key.key_value" : 1})

db.settings.find({ "top_key.key_value" : "value4" })
```

Do let me know if it helps.