# MongoDB, how to query nested Document/object/field in tree like structure

Tags: mongodb, tree, document

I have following document structure stored in Mongodb. Please note "next" is an array.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "pricing": [
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "value": "v1",
      "next": [
        {
          "name": "name2",
          "value": "v2",
          "next": [
            {
              "name": "name3",
              "value": "v3",
              "next": [
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I find the eg. name=name3 or any arbitrary value from it? Not knowing if it exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the field `pricing.next.next.name` and the value `name3` like this.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "pricing.next.next.name": "name3"
})
```

So it will return the document that contains the value `name3` inside the two arrays.

Mongo Playground example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2CO8K-_pfKx)

Your question is not explained too well, so, maybe you mean, how to get only the field `name` after querying by name. Note that you can use other  field like `value` to query the document.

Then, you have to do this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "pricing.next.next.name": "name3",
  
},
{
  "pricing.next.next.name": 1
})
```

And mongo Playground example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hl7K6R6QWg7)

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply. But I wouldn't know if there is an object 3 level down. eg. The pricing next.next could be null

Comment: If ```pricing.next.next``` is null or not exists, then no document will be returned. Is this your doubt?

Comment: I want to search name3 on the entire tree. Not knowing which level it will be or it exists or not

Comment: Then check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802502/mongodb-query-help-query-on-values-of-any-key-in-a-sub-object/19802670#19802670)