# Filter / Search only values of object within MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB i have documents with the following structure:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "570794ee453b02a0001000001"
  },
  "fields_data": {
    "572999c241f1590001000005": "Chicago",
    "572999c241f1590001000007": "Male",
    "572999c241f1590001000013": "Dr.",
    "57299c0741f1590001000023": null,
    "572999c241f1590001000017": "",
    "589886d48570e90001000111": true,
    "58762ac58570e9000100006a": true
  }
}
```

`fields_data` object is very dynamic; the `<field>` of the object is not static.

Is it possible to search or filter only the values of the `fields_data` object?.

Something like:

```
$filter: {
    input: "$fields_data",
    as: "field",
    cond: { $eq: [ "$$field.???", "Male" ] }
}
```

I'm using MongoDB 5.0.4 Community

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**

Thanks for the reply and help. The following worked for me.

```
<used within node>

[
    {
        '$project': {
            'array': {
            '$objectToArray': '$fields_data'
            }, 
            'doc': '$$ROOT'
        }
        }, {
        '$match': {
            'array.v': 'Male'
        }
        }, {
        '$replaceRoot': {
            'newRoot': '$doc'
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is [the answer you looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802502/mongodb-query-help-query-on-values-of-any-key-in-a-sub-object/19802670)
basically you can use $where.
I also agree with the comment that you might reconsider to have your fields_data be an array of objects with "name" and "value" fields so you can have straight normal queries.

Answer (score 0):

Query1

- filter the object and keep the field that is "Male"
- we cant construct paths dynamically, so the only way is to convert the object to array and filter.
- `objectToArray` to convert the embeded document to an array in the form
  `[{"k" : "key1", "v" : "value1"} ....]`
- `filter` and keep only if `"value"="Male"`
- `arrayToObject` to convert back to object like it was

*i think you should change your schema, fields are for the schema, not for saving data in general, if you do this queries become much more complicated and slower

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70702152-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":
  {"fields_data":
   {"$filter":
    {"input":{"$objectToArray":"$fields_data"},
     "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.v", "Male"]}}}}},
 {"$set":{"fields_data":{"$arrayToObject":["$fields_data"]}}}])
```

Query2

- filter the documents and keep those that have the "Male"
- works like the above but only to filter

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70702152-1-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":
  {"$expr":
   {"$ne":
    [{"$filter":
      {"input":{"$objectToArray":"$fields_data"},
       "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.v", "Male"]}}},
     []]}}}])
```